# strip text for individual plots ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to plot boxplot with scales="free_y" but I found out that it is not possible in ggplot2.

So I used

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(boxplot1,boxplot2,boxplot3,ncol=3)
```

The results are very nice but is it possible to text the strips for individual plots, similarly as done using facet_grid()?

I would appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.

Here is the example:

```
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg,aes(x=manufacturer,y=displ))+facet_grid(.~class)+geom_boxplot()
```

now the boxplot can not use scales="free_y"
therefore I did something this

```
box1<-ggplot(subset(mpg,class=="2seater"),aes(x=manufacturer,y=displ))+geom_boxplot()
box2<-ggplot(subset(mpg,class=="minivan"),aes(x=manufacturer,y=displ))+geom_boxplot()
box3<-ggplot(subset(mpg,class=="suv"),aes(x=manufacturer,y=displ))+geom_boxplot()
grid.arrange(box1,box2,box3,ncol=3)
```

the results are nice with appropriate scales but I lose the strip text now on each plot.

Is it possible to get them on individually and then i can use

```
grid.arrange()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please some reproducible example? eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your plots are faceted only by one variable then you can use `facet_wrap()` instead of `facet_grid()`, so you will be able to use `scales="free_y"`.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(as.factor(cyl),mpg))+geom_boxplot()+
          facet_wrap(~gear,scales="free_y")
```

[image]